# Python Selenium login with no source code/html/dom (cursor blinking on username)

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website (private, sorry) that I'm trying to log into automatically but the login page has no source code available so am unable to assign/find specific elements.
The cursor is blinking on the Username input field, so trying somehow to start typing then tab to password field and then enter.
I've tried the following three different methods, neither fills in any text.

ActionChains:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys("*username*")
actions.perform()
```

Passing info to the url itself:

```
driver.get("https://username:password@my_website.com")
```

By active element:

```
active_ele = driver.switch_to.active_element
active_ele.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: Don't understand your statement "has no source code". You can usually see a page's HTML/DOM in the browser, using its "dev tools" or Show Source command.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean by there is no source code, there is not HTML/DOM when I inspect the page. Not until after I login does the DOM populate

Comment: Hmm, what kind of "login page" is this? Is it (something like) the browser's Basic Authentication dialog box (so, not actually a "page")?

Comment: The page is blank with only a pop-up box for Username and Password. When I inspect the HTML it only has <head></head> & <body></body> with nothing inside of either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your target page is protected by Basic Authentication, and what you're calling the "login page" is not an actual "page", but rather the browser's Basic Authentication dialog box. This "pop-up box" is not an actual page element, so you can't manipulate it with Selenium's page-element API.

In my own Selenium code, with current Chrome (version 90), the "https://username:password@my_website.com" URL does actually work to open the target page. However, it doesn't "fill in any text" like you said; it just directly opens the protected page. Also, a "https://username:password@my_website.com" URL doesn't work in the browser address bar itself; it only works in the Selenium API. Also, my tests are in C#; FAIK the "https://username:password@my_website.com" technique might not work in Python.

Note, Chrome removed the "https://username:password@my_website.com" feature for years, but then they brought it back, sometime before November 2019, when I discovered it; but they only brought it back for the Selenium API, not for the browser address bar.